# No of ways of arranging hats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given that there are two types of hats, red and blue, and the count of the red one is $m$ and the count of the blue one is $n$. Now, in how many ways can we arrange the hats in such a way that at any point in the queue, starting from the beginning, the number of red hats encountered is strictly more that the number of blue hats encountered ?

Given $n\geq2$ and $m\geq1$ and $m\gt n$.

Can anyone help me please.
Thank you for help

Comment: This is a version of the [Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: Did you mean to say $m>n$?

Comment: But how can i find number of ways, the Ballot Theorm gives only probabality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of arrangements is $$\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}.$$
As @lulu has given you, the probability that Red is always ahead is $$\frac{m-n}{m+n}$$ so just multiply these two expressions together.